# fast way to get index of top-k elements of every column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: sorting, pandas, indexing, columnsorting

I have a very large pandas dataframe with approximately 500,000 columns.  Each column is about 500 elements long. For each column, I need to retrieve the (index, column) location of the top-k elements in the column.

So, if k were equal to 2, and this were my data frame:

```
  A  B  C  D
w 4  8  10 2
x 5  1  1  6 
y 9  22 25 7 
z 15 5  7  2
```

I would want to return:

```
[(A,y),(A,z),(B,w),(B,y),(C,w),(C,y),(D,x),(D,y)]
```

Keep in mind that I have approximately 500,000 columns, so speed is my primary concern.  Is there a reasonable way of doing this that will not take an entire week on my machine?  What is the fastest way - even if it will be fast enough for the amount of data I have?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem here is what do you really want returned as constructing a list of tuples will be expensive, for instance `df.apply(lambda x: x.sort(inplace=False, ascending=False)[:2])` will return what you want but the `NaN` values are a little unwieldly and probably not what you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `numpy` has a good solution for this that's fast and you can format the output however you want.

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 1000, (200, 500000)), 
                      columns=range(500000), index=range(200))

In [3]: def top_k(x,k):
             ind=np.argpartition(x,-1*k)[-1*k:]
             return ind[np.argsort(x[ind])]

In [69]: %time np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: top_k(x,2),0,df.as_matrix())
CPU times: user 5.91 s, sys: 40.7 ms, total: 5.95 s
Wall time: 6 s

Out[69]:
array([[ 14,  54],
       [178, 141],
       [ 49, 111],
       ...,
       [ 24, 122],
       [ 55,  89],
       [  9, 175]])
```

Pretty fast compared to the pandas solution (which is cleaner IMO but we're going for speed here):

```
In [41]: %time np.array([df[c].nlargest(2).index.values for c in df])
CPU times: user 3min 43s, sys: 6.58 s, total: 3min 49s
Wall time: 4min 8s

Out[41]:
array([[ 54,  14],
       [141, 178],
       [111,  49],
       ...,
       [122,  24],
       [ 89,  55],
       [175,   9]])
```

The lists are in reverse order of each other (you can easily fix this by reversing sort in the `numpy` version)

Note that in the example due to random int generation we can likely have more than `k` values that are equal and max so indices returned may not agree among all methods but all will yield a valid result (you will get `k` indices that match the max values in the column)

Comment: This is a very fast approach and I used it. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide the pandas indexes, only the index numbers.  But it was easy to modify the code to solve that issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good work, feel free to edit the answer to include the mapping to pandas indices if you think it would help others.

Answer (score 8):

Pandas has an efficient `nlargest` operation you can use that is faster than a full sort.  It will still take awhile to apply across 500,000 columns.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (200, 500000)), 
                          columns=range(500000), index=range(200))

In [2]: %time np.array([df[c].nlargest(2).index.values for c in df])
Wall time: 2min 57s
Out[2]: 
array([[171,   1],
       [ 42,  78],
```

As @EdChum noted, you probably don't want to store as tuples, it would be a lot more efficient to use two arrays or some other strategy.

Comment: This should be faster than a temporary sort +1, the problem here is that the `apply` is trying to return a df with the same shape as the original df which is not what can be achieved unless you take the raw values and return some other data structure like in your answer