# Pandas: for groupby value_counts, return the row(s) with the maximum count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do almost the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364601/group-by-and-find-top-n-value-counts-pandas).

However, the approach in the accepted answer by @jezrael takes way too long based on my dataset -- I have ~300k rows in the original dataframe, and it takes a few minutes to run the nlargest(1) command. Furthermore, I tried it on a head(1000) limited dataframe, and didn't get only 1 row for each within the value_count -- I got exactly the same Series back as the value_counts.

**In my own words:** Basically, my dataset has two columns like this:

```
Session Rating
A       Positive
A       Positive
A       Positive
A       Negative
B       Negative
B       Negative
C       Positive
C       Negative
```

Using counts = df.groupby('Session')['Rating'].value_counts() I get a Series object like this:

```
Session Rating
A       Positive  3
        Negative  1
B       Negative  2
C       Positive  1
        Negative  1
```

How do I get a dataframe where just the Rating with the max count is included? And in cases where there are multiple maxes (such as C), I would like to exclude that one from the returned table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192310/2027457 Checkt his way for faster (numpy here will help you better than pandas)

Comment: @0709 I tried the accepted answer on the same dataset he generated, and it didn't give me the same results-- the shape was equal to k for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want something like this.

```
df.groupby('Session')['Rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
```

Output:

```
Session          
A        Positive    3
B        Negative    2
C        Negative    1
Name: Rating, dtype: int64
```

Comment: There must be another way without using apply ? I am having the same challenge on 1M rows...

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte  Try this `df.groupby('Session')['Rating'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(1)`

Comment: @ScottBoston, could you please explain what does level=0 and head(1) do?

Comment: @Reihan_amn Groupby level=0 is grouping by the dataframe index level = 0 if multiindex, if not, it just groups by index.  head(1) gets the first records.   So, in each group get only the first record.